# storing Excel values from a column to a variable in bert

Tags: r, excel

I am currently just trying to get the hang of the BERT console in Excel and am having trouble with simple functionality of storing values from the data set Iris into a variable. I am using the example script from bert which looks like this:

```
#
# Here's an example of using the Excel scripting interface
# (paste this code into the shell). 
# 
# For more information, see
#
# https://bert-toolkit.com/excel-scripting-interface-in-r
#

#
# get a reference to the workbook
#
wb <- EXCEL$Application$get_ActiveWorkbook();

#
# add a sheet
#
new.sheet <- wb$get_Sheets()$Add();

# 
# change the name of the new sheet. note that this will
# fail if a sheet with this name already exists. 
#
new.sheet$put_Name( "R Data Set" );

#
# add some data. use matrices.
#
range <- new.sheet$get_Range( "B3:F152" );
range$put_Value( as.matrix( iris ));

#
# add column headers
#
header.range <- new.sheet$get_Range( "B2:F2" );
header.range$put_Value( t( colnames( iris )));

# 
# resize columns to fit
#
range$get_EntireColumn()$AutoFit();

#
# example of using constants: add border (underline) to headers
#
borders <- header.range$get_Borders();
border <- borders$get_Item( EXCEL$XlBordersIndex$xlEdgeBottom );
border$put_Weight( EXCEL$XlBorderWeight$xlThin );
```

The format of the numbers in the cells are General and I am trying to store the values of column B into a variable so I can manipulate the values. This is the code I tested to grab the values in column B and put them in column G:

```
col.B <- list("B3:B152");
test.input <- new.sheet$get_Range( "G3:G152" );
test.input$put_Value();
```

The output in the command line is TRUE and there is no error but the values are not pasted into column G. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the setup after running your first code chunk, this code copies data from column *B* to column *G*:

```
da_ta <- new.sheet$get_Range("B3:B152")$get_Value()
new.sheet$get_Range("G3:G152")$put_Value(da_ta)
```

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question but this answer is correct :)